# Ephemeral Container kubectl debug prompt issue

Tags: debugging, kubernetes, kubectl, ephemeral-storage

I am trying to test Ephemeral Container in v1.23.5 &  containerd://1.4.9 in minikube v1.23.0

after entering `kubectl debug -it ephemeral-demo --image=busybox:1.35 --target=ephemeral-demo`  , i can see 2 issues

1. prompt displayed improper format. each line is different tab spaces etc
2. when i type ps aux or any commands, cann’t see. but i will be able to see after press enter
   Same issue in Vagrant 2 nodes Cluster with (Ubuntu 21.10) & kube version v1.23.5)

Any one experienced this issue? any suggestions/workarounds appreciated

[image]

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70869568/6309601

Comment: Same for me, i also have the same issue with any images. The aforementioned answer does not help as well. The feature is described in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/ but this issue was not covered by  the documentation. I don't know if there is an issue in the k8s repo.